# undefined variables _POST notice

Tags: php

```
public static function safePostVars()
    {
        if (is_array($_POST))
            return array();
        $_POST = array_map(array('Tools', 'htmlentitiesUTF8'), $_POST);``
    }
```

I received a notice that there is an undefined variables `_POST` for the above code.

Comment: Have a look at the PHP manual: [$_POST](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can not fetch $_POST, $_GET inside function without passing, please try code like :

```
public static function safePostVars($_post_array)
    {
        if (is_array($_post_array))
            return array();
        $_post_array = array_map(array('Tools', 'htmlentitiesUTF8'), $_post_array);``
    }
```

You can call function like:

```
$this->safePostVars($_POST)
```